# Flying-saucer generates PDF with badly justified text

Tags: java, css, pdf, text-align, flying-saucer

Using `<p style="text-align: justify;">...</p>`to justify text generates a paragraph that is not properly justified. It seems that the problem is in the empty space that is left at the end of line.

As generated by flying-saucer: (download simple maven [project](http://www.filedropper.com/flying-saucer))

[image: Paragraph generated by flying-saucer]

In contrast to the expected rendering as in a browser: (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcqfxqvv/))

[image: Justified in browser]

Is there any known workaround for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that flying-soucer does not use the [Paragraph](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/paragraph.html) of the underlying [itext](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7), but splits the text into the individual lines itself. While doing it, flying-soucer does not remove the trailing empty spaces.

A quick fix is to insert `currentLine.trimTrailingSpace(c);` before this call to [save()](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-core/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/layout/InlineBoxing.java#L240).